# Delete list of folders mentioned in text file using p4 delete command

Tags: perforce, p4v

i have a list.txt file which contains all the unused folders in my depot/work space which i need to remove/delete.
From my perforce client i have launched a command line (windows) so i can delete these 300-400 folders quickly.
What command should i use to read the folders from a text file.

What i have tried for 1 path : -

> p4 delete /p4/speech/ramp/themes/projects/cbc/...

similar folder path i have in my list.txt file.. i want p4 delete to be run on each of the 400 paths.

Answer (score 1):

```
p4 -x list.txt delete
```

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/global.options.html

Note that `p4 delete` does more than remove the file(s) from your workspace, but it does not permanently remove them from the depot, so if your goal is either of those it might not be the right command to run.

To remove files from your workspace without affecting anyone else, use `p4 sync #none`.  To remove files from the depot permanently, use `p4 obliterate`.